# Fix an element "DIV" in the bottom of the page before the footer QWEB Invoice Report ODOO

Tags: pdf, odoo, odoo-9, invoice, qweb

**I Want to fix a div element in the bottom of the page, just before the footer in the last page**, it's a qweb report inherited from the standard invoice report of Odoo, the footer it's already visible only in the last page .

Any Idea ? suggestions ?

[Here is a schema of what is wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnpJk.png)

Thanks,

Comment: You can find `report_qweb_element_page_visibility` module in Odoo apps.

Comment: Yes Thanks, I already used this module to make the footer visible only in the last page, but what I want is to place another element just before this footer (not inside the footer), like it's showed in the image I shared

Comment: Try creating div tag and in creation, pass argument 'before' with reference of your 'Footer' tag class.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention your report inherits from the standard invoice report, I assume you already know that the standard invoice layout is a Qweb view named `report_invoice_document` and you have already defined a template like

```
  <template id="your_module.report_invoice_document" priority="50" t-name="Your Module - Modifications to the Standard Invoice Layout"  inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('page')]" position="inside">
      <div>Your content</div>
    </xpath>
  </template>
```

So the only issue is to fine tune both the XPath expression and the position. The whole report is inside a `<div class="page">` tag, so using the above `xpath` tag will put your content just before the report's end.